Issue with Google Sign-In Implementation in ViewModel
I'm facing an issue with my Google Sign-In implementation in an Android application. I have two pieces of code: the first one works correctly, while the second one fails during the call to credentialManager.getCredential(context = context, request = request).
First Code (Working)
class GoogleAuthClient(
    private val context: Context,
    private val credentialManager: CredentialManager,
    private val onSignInComplete: () -> Unit,  // 로그인 완료 콜백 추가
    private val onSignOutComplete: () -> Unit  // 로그아웃 완료 콜백 추가
) {
    companion object {
        private const val TAG = "GoogleAuthClient"
    }

    fun handleSignIn(result: GetCredentialResponse) {
        val credential = result.credential

        when {
            credential.type == GoogleIdTokenCredential.TYPE_GOOGLE_ID_TOKEN_CREDENTIAL -> {
                try {
                    val googleIdTokenCredential =
                        GoogleIdTokenCredential.createFrom(credential.data)

                    val idToken = googleIdTokenCredential.idToken
                    val email = googleIdTokenCredential.id
                    val displayName = googleIdTokenCredential.displayName

                    Log.d(TAG, "Login successful: $email")
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Welcome, $displayName!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    onSignInComplete()  // 로그인 완료 알림

                } catch (e: GoogleIdTokenParsingException) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Invalid Google ID token", e)
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Login failed: Invalid token", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show()
                }
            }

            else -> {
                Log.e(TAG, "Unexpected credential type")
                Toast.makeText(context, "Login failed: Unexpected error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
    }

    fun signOut() {
        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch {
            try {
                credentialManager.clearCredentialState(
                    ClearCredentialStateRequest(
                        ClearCredentialStateRequest.TYPE_CLEAR_CREDENTIAL_STATE
                    )
                )
                Toast.makeText(context, "Signed out successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                onSignOutComplete()  // 로그아웃 완료 알림
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Logout failed", e)
                Toast.makeText(context, "Logout failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
    }
} 
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    private lateinit var googleAuthClient: GoogleAuthClient
    private lateinit var credentialManager: CredentialManager
    private var isSignedIn = false
    private lateinit var signInOutText: TextView

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        signInOutText = TextView(this).apply {
            text = "Sign In"
            textSize = 18f
            setPadding(32, 32, 32, 32)
            setOnClickListener { handleSignInOutClick() }
        }
        setContentView(signInOutText)

        credentialManager = CredentialManager.create(this)
        googleAuthClient = GoogleAuthClient(
            this,
            credentialManager,
            onSignInComplete = {
                isSignedIn = true
                signInOutText.text = "Sign Out"
            },
            onSignOutComplete = {
                isSignedIn = false
                signInOutText.text = "Sign In"
            }
        )
    }

    private fun handleSignInOutClick() {
        if (!isSignedIn) {
            signInWithGoogle()
        } else {
            googleAuthClient.signOut()
        }
    }

    private fun signInWithGoogle() {
        val nonce = generateNonce()
        val signInWithGoogleOption = GetSignInWithGoogleOption.Builder(
            "909240456210-gomip46dc5200lbd8vdrs2ii94clss4t.apps.googleusercontent.com")
            .setNonce(nonce)
            .build()
        Log.d("haha", "signInWithGoogleOption 성공")

        val request = GetCredentialRequest.Builder()
            .addCredentialOption(signInWithGoogleOption)
            .build()

        Log.i("haha", "GetCredentialRequest 성공")

        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch {
            try {
                val result = credentialManager.getCredential(
                    request = request,
                    context = this@MainActivity
                )
                Log.d("haha", "getCredential 성공")

                googleAuthClient.handleSignIn(result)
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                println("Login failed: ${e.message}")
            }
        }
    }

    private fun generateNonce(): String {
        val randomBytes = ByteArray(32)
        SecureRandom().nextBytes(randomBytes)
        return randomBytes.joinToString("") { "%02x".format(it) }
    }
}

Second Code (Not Working)
fun NavGraphBuilder.loginComposable(
    onNavigateToGenderAndAgeGroup: (Map<String, Any?>) -> Unit,
    onNavigateToQuote: () -> Unit
) {
    composable(route = "login") {
        val loginViewModel: LoginViewModel = hiltViewModel()
        val pendingUserMap = loginViewModel.pendingUserMap.collectAsState().value

        LoginScreen(
            loginViewModel = loginViewModel,
            onNavigateToGenderAndAgeGroup = {
                pendingUserMap?.let { onNavigateToGenderAndAgeGroup(it) }
            },
            onNavigateToQuote = onNavigateToQuote
        )
    }
}
----------------
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object AppModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideContext(@ApplicationContext context: Context): Context {
        return context
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideClientId(@ApplicationContext context: Context): String {
        return context.getString(R.string.client_id)
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideCredentialManager(@ApplicationContext context: Context): CredentialManager {
        return CredentialManager.create(context)
    }
}
--------------------
@Composable
fun LoginScreen(
    loginViewModel: LoginViewModel,
    onNavigateToGenderAndAgeGroup: () -> Unit,
    onNavigateToQuote: () -> Unit
) {
    val context = LocalContext.current
    val authState by loginViewModel.authState.collectAsState()

    when (authState) {
        is AuthState.Loading -> {
            CircularProgressIndicator(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize())
        }

        is AuthState.SignedOut -> {
            LoginScreenContent(onGoogleLoginClick = {
                loginViewModel.onGoogleLoginClicked()
            })
        }

        is AuthState.SignedIn -> {
            LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
                onNavigateToQuote()
            }
        }

        is AuthState.SignUpRequired -> {
            LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
                onNavigateToGenderAndAgeGroup()
            }
        }

        is AuthState.Error -> {
            val errorMessage = (authState as AuthState.Error).message
            Toast.makeText(context, errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }
}


@Composable
fun LoginScreenContent(
    onGoogleLoginClick: () -> Unit
) {
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .background(BlackBackground),
    ) {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .offset(x = 34.dp, y = 99.dp)
                .align(Alignment.TopStart),
        )  {

        }
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .align(Alignment.BottomCenter)
                .padding(bottom = 80.dp),
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(12.dp, Alignment.Top),
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.Start,
        ) {
            GoogleLoginButton(onGoogleLoginClick)
        }
    }
}

@Composable
private fun GoogleLoginButton(
    onGoogleLoginClick: () -> Unit
) {
    Row(
        modifier = Modifier
            .width(345.dp)
            .height(54.dp)
            .background(color = GrayScaleWhite, shape = RoundedCornerShape(size = 10.dp))
            .padding(start = 17.dp)
            .clickable(onClick = onGoogleLoginClick),
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(79.dp, Alignment.Start),
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
    ) {
        Image(
            modifier = Modifier
                .width(24.dp)
                .height(24.dp)
                .background(color = GrayScaleWhite),
            painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.google_icon),
            contentDescription = "google_icon",
            contentScale = ContentScale.None,
        )
        Text(
            text = stringResource(id = R.string.google_login),
            style = TextStyle(
                fontSize = 18.sp,
                fontFamily = FontFamily(Font(R.font.inter_18pt_regular)),
                fontWeight = FontWeight(400),
                color = Color(0xFF000000),
            ),
        )
    }
}
---------------------------
@HiltViewModel
class LoginViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val credentialManager: CredentialManager,
    private val clientId: String,
    @ApplicationContext private val applicationContext: Context // 애플리케이션 컨텍스트 추가
) : ViewModel() {
    private val tag = "LoginViewModel: "
    private val firebaseAuth: FirebaseAuth = Firebase.auth
    private val firestore: FirebaseFirestore = Firebase.firestore

    private val _authState = MutableStateFlow<AuthState>(AuthState.SignedOut)
    val authState: StateFlow<AuthState> = _authState.asStateFlow()

    private val _pendingUserMap = MutableStateFlow<Map<String, Any?>?>(null)
    val pendingUserMap: StateFlow<Map<String, Any?>?> = _pendingUserMap.asStateFlow()

    init {
        checkInitialAuthState()
    }

    private fun checkInitialAuthState() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            _authState.value = if (isSignedIn()) {
                val currentUser = getCurrentUser()
                if (currentUser != null) AuthState.SignedIn(currentUser) else AuthState.SignedOut
            } else {
                AuthState.SignedOut
            }
        }
    }

    fun isSignedIn(): Boolean = firebaseAuth.currentUser != null

    suspend fun getCurrentUser(): User? {
        val currentUser = firebaseAuth.currentUser ?: return null

        return try {
            val userDoc = firestore.collection("users")
                .document(currentUser.uid)
                .get()
                .await()

            userDoc.toObject(User::class.java)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            if (e is CancellationException) throw e
            logError("Error fetching current user: ${e.message}")
            null
        }
    }

    fun onGoogleLoginClicked() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            val state = signIn()
            _authState.value = state
        }
    }

    private suspend fun signIn(): AuthState {
        return try {
            if (isSignedIn()) {
                val currentUser = getCurrentUser()
                Log.d(tag, "이미 로그인 상태입니다. 사용자: $currentUser")
                return AuthState.SignedIn(currentUser)
            }

            val result = buildCredentialRequest()
            Log.d(tag, "Credential 요청 성공: $result")

            handleSignIn(result)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.e(tag, "Sign-in failed: ${e.message}", e)
            AuthState.Error("Sign-in failed: ${e.message}")
        }
    }

    private suspend fun buildCredentialRequest(): GetCredentialResponse {
        val nonce = generateNonce()
        val signInWithGoogleOption = GetSignInWithGoogleOption.Builder(clientId)
            .setNonce(nonce)
            .build()

        val request = GetCredentialRequest.Builder()
            .addCredentialOption(signInWithGoogleOption)
            .build()

        return credentialManager.getCredential(context = applicationContext, request = request)
    }

    private fun generateNonce(): String {
        val randomBytes = ByteArray(32)
        SecureRandom().nextBytes(randomBytes)
        return randomBytes.joinToString("") { "%02x".format(it) }
    }

    private fun logError(message: String) {
        Log.e(tag, message)
    }

    private suspend fun handleSignIn(result: GetCredentialResponse): AuthState {
        Log.d(tag, "{handleSignIn 진입 완료}")
        val credential = result.credential
        if (credential is CustomCredential &&
            credential.type == GoogleIdTokenCredential.TYPE_GOOGLE_ID_TOKEN_CREDENTIAL
        ) {
            try {
                val tokenCredential = GoogleIdTokenCredential.createFrom(credential.data)
                val authCredential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(
                    tokenCredential.idToken, null
                )
                val authResult = firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(authCredential).await()
                val firebaseUser = authResult.user
                return if (firebaseUser != null) {
                    val userExists = checkUserExistsInFirestore(firebaseUser.uid)
                    if (!userExists) {
                        val initialProfile = createInitialProfile(firebaseUser)
                        _pendingUserMap.value = initialProfile
                        AuthState.SignUpRequired
                    } else {
                        val userDocument = firestore.collection("users")
                            .document(firebaseUser.uid).get().await()
                        val user = userDocument.toObject(User::class.java)
                        AuthState.SignedIn(user)
                    }
                } else {
                    AuthState.SignedOut
                }
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Log.e(tag, "Sign-in error: ${e.message}", e)
                return AuthState.Error("Sign-in failed: ${e.message}")
            }
        } else {
            Log.e(tag, "credential is not GoogleIdTokenCredential")
            return AuthState.SignedOut
        }
    }

    private suspend fun checkUserExistsInFirestore(userId: String): Boolean {
        return try {
            firestore.collection("users").document(userId).get().await().exists()
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
            false
        }
    }

    private fun createInitialProfile(firebaseUser: FirebaseUser): Map<String, Any?> {
        return mapOf(
            "uid" to firebaseUser.uid,
            "email" to firebaseUser.email,
            "displayName" to firebaseUser.displayName
        )
    }
}



In the second code, when I call credentialManager.getCredential(context = context, request = request), it throws an error. However, I have verified that the GCP settings and SHA-1 configurations are correct since the first code works perfectly in the same project.
What could be causing the credentialManager.getCredential call to fail in the second code?
error shown on logcat is "[28444] Developer console is not set up correctly.".
Any insights or suggestions on how to troubleshoot this issue would be greatly appreciated!

Could you please share the type of error you are encountering? Also, we cannot use context inside the ViewModel as it can cause memory leaks.

First of all, thank you for your help. The error message is "[28444] Developer console is not set up correctly." This occurs in the second code at the credentialManager.getCredential(context = context, request = request) part within the buildCredentialRequest() function. Thank you.
Feel free to let me know if you need further assistance!

I just revised my code to avoid using context inside the viewmodel but the error is still not fixed :( -> Error Log: 2024-12-07 01:06:05.163 24172-24186 CredManProvService      com.example.passionDaily             I  GetCredentialResponse error returned from framework
2024-12-07 01:06:05.173 24172-24172 LoginViewModel:         com.example.passionDaily             E  Sign-in failed: [28444] Developer console is not set up correctly.
